# Generating And / Or Conditions Automatically from a List

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

> l1 = {x y, s t, a b}

From this list, I am trying to essentially generate a new list that looks like this:

```
    l1 = {x==1 && y==1 && s == 0 && t == 0 && a == 0 && b == 0
|| x == 0 && y == 0 && s == 1 && t == 1 && a == 0 && b == 0
|| x == 0 && y == 0 && s == 0 && t == 0 && a == 1 && b == 1}
```

I.e., only one pair at a time can take on the value of 1 in each OR statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l1 = {x y, s t, a b}; 

res1 = {Or @@ 
  Inner[Sequence @@ Thread[Equal[List @@ #2, #]] &, IdentityMatrix[Length @ l1], l1, And]}
```

> {(x == 1 && y == 1 && s == 0 && t == 0 && a == 0 && 
>       b == 0) ||
>    (x == 0 && y == 0 && s == 1 && t == 1 && a == 0 && 
>       b == 0) ||
>   (x == 0 && y == 0 && s == 0 && t == 0 && a == 1 && 
>       b == 1)}

Alternatively,

```
l2 = Flatten[l1 /. Times -> List]
```

> {x, y, s, t, a, b}

```
res2 = {Or @@ 
  Inner[Equal[#2, #] &, Riffle[#, #] & /@ IdentityMatrix[Length[l2]/2], l2,  And]}
```

> {(x == 1 && y == 1 && s == 0 && t == 0 && a == 0 && 
>       b == 0) ||
>    (x == 0 && y == 0 && s == 1 && t == 1 && a == 0 && 
>       b == 0) ||
>   (x == 0 && y == 0 && s == 0 && t == 0 && a == 1 && 
>       b == 1)}

Comment: Hi @kglr . I tried this solution, and it works great. The only problem I am having is that it doesn't work exactly as expected because your l1 is slightly different then mine. In your l1, you have l1 = {x,y,s,t,a,b}, but I have l1 = {x y, s t, a b}, i.e., each element in the list contains a product.

Comment: @ThomasMoore, you can use `l0 = {x y, s t, a b};
l1 = Flatten[l0 /. Times -> List]`. I will post an alternative approach using `{x y, s t, a b}` directly.

Comment: Hi @kglr Thank you very much. It is much appreciated!