# Generating Logical Constraints from a List

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an equation, call it l1, that looks like this:

```
e1 = x*y*z + t*u*v + a*b*c
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to generate a boolean expression like this from any such given equation:

```
  ( (x==1 && y == 1 && z==1) && (t==0 && u==0 && v ==0) && (a==0 && b ==0 && c==0) || 
( ( (x==0 && y == 0 && z==0) && (t==1 && u==1 && v ==1) && (a==0 && b ==0 && c==0) ||
 ( (x==0 && y == 0 && z==0) && (t==0 && u==0 && v ==0) && (a==1 && b ==1 && c==1)
```

I.e., each variable in each term cyclically takes on the value 1 while the others are all zero. Is it possible to flexibly do this in Mathematica. Flexibly, in the sense that some equations may have 4 or 5 or 6 terms, and some of the terms may have 2 variables or 4 variables.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** An alternative method inspired by Roman's answer:

```
f0 = Reduce[{# == 1, ##& @@ Equal @@@ #, ##& @@ Thread[0<=Variables[#]<=1]}, Integers]&;

f0[x y z + t u v + a b c]
```

> (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0 && t == 0 && u == 0 && v == 0 && x == 1 &&
>       y == 1 && z == 1) ||
>    (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0 && t == 1 && 
>      u == 1 && v == 1 && x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0) ||
>    (a == 1 && 
>      b == 1 && c == 1 && t == 0 && u == 0 && v == 0 && x == 0 && 
>      y == 0 && z == 0)

```
f0[x y + t u v + a b c d;]
```

> (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0 && d == 0 && t == 0 && u == 0 && v == 0 &&
>           x == 1 && y == 1) ||
>   (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0 && d == 0 && 
>          t == 1 && u == 1 && v == 1 && x == 0 && y == 0) ||
>    (a == 1 && 
>          b == 1 && c == 1 && d == 1 && t == 0 && u == 0 && v == 0 && 
>          x == 0 && y == 0)

**Original answer:**

You can use the approach in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/208442/125) after pre-processing the input expression to replace `Plus` with `List`:

```
e1 = x y z + t u v + a b c;
l1 = e1 /. Plus -> List
```

> {a b c, t u v, x y z}

```
Or @@ Inner[Sequence @@ Thread[Equal[List @@ #2, #]] &, 
  IdentityMatrix[Length@l1], l1, And]
```

> (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1 && t == 0 && u == 0 && v == 0 && x == 0 &&
>       y == 0 && z == 0) ||
>    (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0 && t == 1 && 
>      u == 1 && v == 1 && x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0) ||
>   (a == 0 && 
>      b == 0 && c == 0 && t == 0 && u == 0 && v == 0 && x == 1 && 
>      y == 1 && z == 1)

This approach works for arbitrary number of terms in the input expression and arbitrary number of variables in each term:

```
e2 = x y + t u v + a b c d;
l2 = e2 /. Plus -> List
```

> {a b c d, t u v, x y}

```
Or @@ Inner[Sequence @@ Thread[Equal[List @@ #2, #]] &, 
  IdentityMatrix[Length@l2], l2, And]
```

> (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1 && d == 1 && t == 0 && u == 0 && v == 0 &&
>       x == 0 && y == 0) ||
>    (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0 && d == 0 && 
>      t == 1 && u == 1 && v == 1 && x == 0 && y == 0) ||
>    (a == 0 && 
>      b == 0 && c == 0 && d == 0 && t == 0 && u == 0 && v == 0 && 
>      x == 1 && y == 1)

Comment: Thanks @kglr this is excellent!

Answer (score 1):

As a combination of logical and numerical constraints,

```
(e1 /. {Times -> Equal, Plus -> And}) &&
e1 == 1 && 
Element[Variables[e1], Integers] && 
And @@ Thread[0 <= Variables[e1] <= 1]

(*    a == b == c && t == u == v && x == y == z &&
      a b c + t u v + x y z == 1 &&
      (a | b | c | t | u | v | x | y | z) \[Element] Integers && 
      0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= c <= 1 &&
      0 <= t <= 1 && 0 <= u <= 1 && 0 <= v <= 1 &&
      0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1    *)
```

This gives the right answer:

```
Solve[%, Variables[e1]]

(*    {{a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0, t -> 0, u -> 0, v -> 0, x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 1},
       {a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0, t -> 1, u -> 1, v -> 1, x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0},
       {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, t -> 0, u -> 0, v -> 0, x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0}}    *)
```